# "su - user" not working the same when scripted

Tags: path, su

I have a program that was installed under "/home/user" and whose commands ONLY work if I execute them from the command line like so:

```
root@server:~# su - user
user@server:~# command
```

However, I am trying to script these commands like so:

```
su - user -c 'command'
```

Although the script executes and command is 'run", parts of the program do not work correctly.

I made sure the $PATH variable was the same between "root" and "user", and added a couple environmental variables that were in /home/user/.profile to the root one. Still, something is missing.

What is special about "su - user" from command line vs in a script, and how can I account for what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure what is different in the hidden parts of your command. But I would like to point out things that may help:

- Consider the difference between single and double quotas: `'command'` and `"command"`. The latter will expand content: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/ So if I write in my shell `su - myname -c 'echo $PATH'`, I see a very different path than with `su - myname -c "echo $PATH"`.
- Try to find out more by "debugging" like `su - myname -c "echo SHOW_ME_SOMETHING"`. Maybe you can observe subparts of your `command` working differently.
- Handling of the path is tricky, meaning there is login emulating with different reset states on different systems. Have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/193277/what-happens-to-the-environment-when-you-run-su-c

Hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow, I stumbled upon the answer.
I assumed a file I sourced (and defined $PATH) in /etc/bash.bashrc would follow through everywhere.  Apparently this was not the case.  So I sourced that file AGAIN in /home/user/.profile, and NOW it works.

Comment: @Corepuncher: Thanks for filing your final solution, I'm sure it will help somebody some time :-)